# Django filter based on retrieved values

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I have a model which contains a few parameters like the following

```
{ "user_name" : "john",
  "enter_time" : 1442257970.509184,
   "frequency" : 30
}
```

I need to write a filter functions , preferably using django-filter or any other pythonic-way so that, I could filter out those records where in

```
def test():
 cur_time = time.time() 
 if cur_time >= enter_time + frequency:
  return True
 return False
```

Currently in my views.py I am able to filter based on names and single values.
For example,

```
records = UserRecord.objects.filter(token=user_token, user_name=name, status='active').distinct()
serializer = RecordSerializer(records, many=True)
```

I am not sure, how to filter out based on the test condition defined in the test(). One workaround was to get serializer.data and process a list of OrderedDictionaries to filter out the content. But I am looking for django way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use F expressions in filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters). In your case:

```
UserRecord.objects.annotate(time_plus_freq=F('enter_time')+F('frequency'))\
    .filter(time_plus_freq__lt=cur_time)
```

This way filtering is done in the SQL and you do not need to do any on the Python side.

If Django has trouble defining the type of the annotated expression look at [`output_field` kwarg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#output-field) in annotate.

Comment: I tried doing that, I m getting django error "Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field"

Comment: enter_time and frequency are Float and Int respectively. I havent used Datetime formats while defining the model.

Comment: oops my bad. I have set both frequency and enter_time to models.FloatField . It seems fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really want to do it directly, there is a way but it will be done on application-level, not on database-level. You can simply make generator like this:

```
records = (record for record in records if test(record))
```

but this is really bad and you should avoid it.

Much better solution is to rewrite your test condition, so it will use django queryset filtering, like it was mentioned in Ivan's answer.